# Получить список заявок

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы, нужно получить список client_id, последние заявки (title) которых не обработаны. Считаем, что если был звонок после создания заявки (created_datetime) то она обработана.

| tasks |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| client_id | created_datetime | title |

| calls |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| manager_id | client_id | call_datetime |

Чувствую, что нужно что-то сделать со временем, но не пойму что.

```
select client_id, max(calls.call_datetime)  - max(tasks.created_datetime) as time
from tasks join calls on tasks.client_id = calls.client_id 
group by client_id , call_datetime
```

Comment: `having time < 0` наверное. А зачем у вас группировка по `call_datetime`? Это вроде лишнее. И ещё нужно предусмотреть случай, когда нет вообще ни одной соответствующей записи в `tasks`, то есть нужно во-первых сделать `LEFT JOIN`, а во-вторых обработать случай, когда вместо значений правой таблицы будут `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понимаю, то примерно так:

```
select client_id
from tasks 
left join calls on tasks.client_id = calls.client_id 
group by client_id
having calls.call_datetime is NULL or
    max(calls.call_datetime) < max(tasks.created_datetime)
```

Подробнее - см. мой комментарий к вопросу.